# mod_Rewrite conditions and rules ( confused ) help please

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Help please,

After numerous hours searching for the solution to my problem i have become completely confused, so my appologies if this as been answered before.

I have a current URL as so :

http://www.mydomain.com/news/dentistry_dental/article_detail.php?article=2968&title=redefining-oral-hygiene-intervention

I am cleaning up my urls so have now created a rewrite rule to parse the following to the previous url :

http://www.mydomain.com/dental_news/2968/Redefining-oral-hygiene-intervention

The rule i have used in the .htaccess file for this is as below :

```
RewriteRule ^dental_news/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /news/dentistry_dental/article_detail.php?article=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

This is working as expected, however.. I need to also have the OLD url ( That is indexed on many Search Engines ) to now point to the NEW url with a 301 redirect.

I have tried numerous things but as of yet i get nothing but errors, i presume its a looping error i have.

Does anyone out there have any idea how i can achieve the 2 way redirect without looping?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

**EDIT**

The above problem has been resolved, as you can see by the answer below, however i now have another query, this should help me in understanding whats going on i hope :)

I have another URL `www.mydomain.com/news/dentistry_dental/index.php` that i want to redirect with 301 to `www.mydomain.com/dental_news/`

I have tried rewriting the code from the answer below to do this but it was a fail, i am still lacking understanding of the whole thing i think.

Any help be great :)

Regards
M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following.  The first condition should protect you from a redirect loop (it only matches requests not beginning with `/dental_news`.  The `%1` and `%2` will match the corresponding regex groups from the previous `RewriteCond`.  Also, the trailing `?` on the `RewriteRule`, will remove the querystring on redirect.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/dental_news\/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} article=([0-9]*)&title=(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /dental_news/%1/%2? [L,R=301]
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**:
I changed the last group of the second `RewriteCond` to match up until the `$` of `$fr=1`, if this is intended to be `&1`, you can change the end of the `RewriteCond` to group `([^&]*)` instead.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/dental_news\/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} article=([0-9]*)&title=([^$]*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /dental_news/%1/%2? [L,R=301]
```

**EDIT**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^dental_news/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ news/dentistry_dental/article_detail.php?article=$1&title=$2&redirect [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dental_news/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} article=([0-9]*)&title=([^&]*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /dental_news/%1/%2? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: @clmarquart Many thanks for your help, there is deffinately something good going on, however how would i use this in conjunction with my other rule, which does the other way round? 

As if i add this to my .htaccess there is still some sort of loop going on. If remove my rule, the redirect works however its a 404 as i have removed my rule. 

I Hope this makes sense :)

Cheers again for your help

Comment: On your original `RewriteRule`, is the last parameter on the rewrite supposed to be `$fr` or `&fr`? In either case, I didn't notice it the first time, and I'll update my original answer to fix the issue.

Comment: the $fr isnt meant to be there at all, and has been removed that was for me trying to do redirect with php ( not possible due to headers issue ) so the $fr=1 should be removed form my orignal post which ill do now :)

Comment: @clmarquart , Still same issue, i removed the $fr from the string, and used orignal code you provided, but its looping :/ . This rewrite stuff is tough :(

Comment: Alright, I'm not sure if this is how I've done it in the past, but I've updated the answer once more....hopefully it will work for you.

Comment: @clmarquart Fantastic you are a Star!! Thank you so very much for your help. Works a treat! nowim going to try figure out what all that actually does :)

Comment: @clmarquart one more question, i still dont really get the logix/expressions in this, if i wanted to do the following what would the code be, i tried using something similar to which you wrote however it didnt work out :O

http://www.mydomain.com/news/dentistry_dental/index.php
To forward to
http://www.mydomain.com/dental_news/

I tried this :

`code`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dental_news/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} news/dentistry_dental/index.php$
(.*) /dental_news/? [L,R=301]`code`

Comment: Can you post a new question, or edit this one, it's kinda hard to tell what's going on there...and it looks like its missing a `RewriteRule`.

Comment: @clmarquart I have edited the original towards the bottom, Regards M

Comment: Add the following rule: `RewriteRule  ^news/dentistry_dental/index.php$ /dental_news/ [L,R=301]`

Comment: Ok, this works but i have some issues i am going to post a new question, if you can help out further that would be fantastic. If not thanks so much for your help thus far.

Comment: Part 2 of this can be found

[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640491/mod-redirect-and-rewrites-part-2