# mod redirect and rewrites ( Part 2 )

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Further to my previous questions i am getting my self into a mess, so i will try and lay my problem/s out as best as i can here.

I am tidying up my URL structure but have the problem that my urls are well indexed in Search engines, so i need to rewrite my urls while also redirect them.

With help earlier on a previous question i currently have the following in my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

rewritecond %{http_host} ^mydomain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

# Rewrite all index.php to root: / ( with perm redirect )
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301]

# Rewrite A newly added section rewrite ( no redirect required )
RewriteRule ^products/digital_imaging/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /products/digital_xray.php?id=$1&product=$2 [L]

# Rewrite dental news article to neat nice url
RewriteRule ^dental_news/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ news/dentistry_dental/article_detail.php?article=$1&title=$2&redirect [L]

#Conditional rewrite of old news article path to new one with 301 redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dental_news/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} article=([0-9]*)&title=([^&]*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /dental_news/%1/%2? [L,R=301]
```

So, this is all working as expected, but i have another url that ends in a index.php that sometimes but not always has php variables, this i also need to rewrite and redirect, by trying to do it myself i am creating a conflict of some sorts, and its not working as expected.

The URL i need to rewrite & redirect with a 301 is below

```
http://www.mydomain.com/news/dentistry_dental/index.php?month=February&year=2011

With the previous index.php rule it currently displays as

http://www.mydomain.com/news/dentistry_dental/?month=February&year=2011

Half way there i guess... I need it to be the following

http://www.mydomain.com/dental_news/February/2011
```

Baring in mind that the url sometimes has no variables as below

```
http://www.mydomain.com/news/dentistry_dental/index.php

Which is currently with the index.php rule above is showing as

http://www.mydomain.com/news/dentistry_dental/

This needs to be

http://www.mydomain.com/dental_news/
```

So yes, i am totally crap at this stuff, it is entirely new to me, so if i can get this sorted ill be a very happy bunny indeed!

Thanks All

**EDIT**

Ok my current .htaccess looks as below.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

rewritecond %{http_host} ^mydomain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

# Rewrite all index.php to root: / ( with perm redirect )
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteRule ^products/digital_imaging/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /products/digital_xray.php?id=$1&product=$2 [L]

# Rewrite dental news article to neat nice url
RewriteRule ^dental_news/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ news/dentistry_dental/article_detail.php?article=$1&title=$2&redirect [L]

#Conditional rewrite of old news article path to new one with 301 redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dental_news/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} article=([0-9]*)&title=([^&]*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /dental_news/%1/%2? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} month=([^&]*)&year=([^&]*)
RewriteRule (.*) /dental_news/%1/%2? [R=301]
RewriteRule news/dentistry_dental/$ /dental_news/ [R=301]
RewriteRule ^dental_news/$ /news/dentistry_dental/index.php [L]
```

As it stands with this, The following occurs

```
www.mydomain.com/news/dentistry_dental/index.php 
-> www.mydomain.com/dental_news/
```

( ^ Correct )

```
www.mydomain.com/news/dentistry_dental/index.php?month=May&year=2011 
-> www.mydomain.com/dental_news/April/2011
```

( ^ Wrong : Showing right path in url bar, but displaying article_detail.php instead of index.php with variables)

I am guessing that 2 of the rules are similar and one is picking up the index.php with year and month variables and sending to article_detail page. I might be wrong however and i have no idea how to fix.

**EDIT #2**

Current .htaccess as below.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

rewritecond %{http_host} ^dentalsupportuk.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.dentalsupportuk.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

# Rewrite all index.php to root: / ( with perm redirect )
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.dentalsupportuk.com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteRule ^products/digital_imaging/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /products/digital_xray.php?id=$1&product=$2 [L]

# Rewrite dental news article to neat nice url
RewriteRule ^dental_news/([0-9]*)/([^/]*)$ news/dentistry_dental/article_detail.php?article=$1&title=$2&redirect [L]

#Conditional rewrite of old news article path to new one with 301 redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dental_news/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} article=([0-9]*)&title=([^&]*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /dental_news/%1/%2? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} month=([^&]*)&year=([^&]*)
RewriteRule (.*) /dental_news/%1/%2? [R=301]
RewriteRule news/dentistry_dental/$ /dental_news/ [R=301]
RewriteRule ^dental_news/([a-zA-Z]*)/([0-9]*)$ news/dentistry_dental/index.php?month=$1&year=$2&redirect [L]
```

www.mydomain.com/dental_news/ is now **rewriting** to  www.mydomain.com/dental_news/ which doesnt exist so 404 error ( should be rewriting to www.mydomain.com/news/dentistry_dental/ )

www.mydomain.com/dental_news/100/some-title is now **rewriting** as expected to www.mydomain.com/news/dentistry_dental/article_detail.php with the variables ( working )

www.mydomain.com/news/dentistry_dental/article_detail.php?article=100&title=some-title is **redirecting** as expected to www.mydomain.com/dental_news/100/some-title and displaying correctly ( working )

www.mydomain.com/news/dentistry_dental/index.php?month=May&year=2010 is **redirecting** but crashing out Firefox stating ( Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete. ) ( Not Working, is this some sort of loop causing this? )

www.mydomain.com/dental_news/July/2010/   the **rewriting** is giving me a 404 error.

So yes, im all over the place, maybe ive put in wrong order or something, but the more i mess the more im scared of breaking everything. Any ideas?

Regards
M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the follow two rules:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} month=([^&]*)&year=([^&]*)
RewriteRule (.*) /dental_news/%1/%2? [R=301]

RewriteRule news/dentistry_dental/$ /dental_news/ [R=301]
```

I don't believe it causes any conflicts, and seems to cover the two scenarios you described.

**EDIT**

OK, so if I'm getting this correct, the URLs that are `/dental_news/2968/Redefining-oral-hygiene-intervention` should be rewritten to `/news/dentistry_dental/article_detail.php` with the proper querystrings.  And then the `/dental_news/April/2011` should be rewritten to `/news/dentistry_dental/index.php`.  So...if that is the case, you should be able to add the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^dental_news/([a-zA-Z]*)/([0-9]*)$ news/dentistry_dental/index.php?month=$1&year=$2&redirect [L]
```

It would also probably make sense to make the following update:

Current: `RewriteRule ^dental_news/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ news/dentistry_dental/article_detail.php?article=$1&title=$2&redirect [L]`

Updated: `RewriteRule ^dental_news/([0-9]*)/([^/]*)$ news/dentistry_dental/article_detail.php?article=$1&title=$2&redirect [L]`

The difference there being that it is more specific, and the first regex group will only match a group of digits, and will help to avoid conflict with your rule that is rewriting to the `index.php` file.

**EDIT 2**
I believe I tested all of the URLs you provided, and they seem to be working now.  There were a couple of redirect loops that we weren't accounting for.  Hopefully this will help...

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

rewritecond %{http_host} ^mydomain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

# Rewrite all index.php to root: / ( with perm redirect )
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteRule ^products/digital_imaging/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /products/digital_xray.php?id=$1&product=$2 [L]

RewriteRule dental_news/$ /news/dentistry_dental/?rewrite [L]

# Rewrite dental news article to neat nice url
# Protect from looping because of previous rules
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !rewrite 
RewriteRule ^dental_news/([0-9]*)/([^/]*)$ news/dentistry_dental/article_detail.php?article=$1&title=$2&rewrite [L]

#Conditional rewrite of old news article path to new one with 301 redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dental_news/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} article=([0-9]*)&title=([^&]*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /dental_news/%1/%2? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dental_news/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} month=([^&]*)&year=([^&]*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /dental_news/%1/%2? [R=301]


# Protect from looping because of previous rules
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !rewrite 
RewriteRule news/dentistry_dental/$ /dental_news/ [R=301]

# Protect from looping because of previous rules
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !rewrite 
RewriteRule ^dental_news/([a-zA-Z]*)/([0-9]*)/?$ news/dentistry_dental/index.php?month=$1&year=$2&rewrite [L]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @clmarquart Hi, thanks again for your input. I have added the rules, you have suggested, when clicking the new link it redirects to 
www.mydomain.com/dental_news/
but its giving a 404, the apache logs saying its actually looking for the file, rather than just rewriting real address?

Comment: No problem.  You will want to add another rewrite that points the new URL to the actual file, probably something like: `RewriteRule ^dental_news/$ /news/dentistry_dental/index.php [L]`

Comment: @clmarquart There is deffinately some progress, but still some problems, sorry to be a pain, i have edited the question above at the bottom, maybe you can see the problem. Thanks M

Comment: @clmarquart Yes you are getting the idea of what im needing, but im stilling getting loop errors, i will edit original question now, so you can see. Probably my fault no doubt doing something wrong.

Comment: @clmarquart after virtually no sleep im still having same problem, i just cant figure it out :( **EDIT 2** in question above explains.

Comment: Alright, so I updated my answer, added the complete `.htaccess` file I used to test.  And it seems to be working, you were correct, there were some redirect loops, that should now be fixed.

Comment: Just checked it out, all seems ot be working as expected, fantastic! i did play with some other rewrite stuff and got almost everything working, but your ruleset works flawlessly! thank you very much!

Comment: @clmarquart Hi again, I just wandered if it would be easy enough to rewrite my other pages that have .php extension so they have no extension so about-us.php would become about-us With a 301 also, without ruining the other rules, i Know i can do it with 

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php `

But dont want to mess up things, what you think?

Regards M

Comment: Just by looking at it, it seems like it should be fine, since the other rules are checking for /news or /dental_news. So, if you put the new rule last, you should be OK.

Comment: @clmarquart Yes this works perfectly :) one thing i cant seem to do without internal server error is add a trailing / at the end of urls, strange.